# Save file per-branch in git, don't need it's history though, don't want it pushed to remote

Tags: git

I'd like to save the [.suo file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) per branch so if I switch between branches/features I can easily load the last set of files I was working on.

Is it possible to do this with git?

I definitely don't want the file to be pushed to the remote, and having history on the file seems completely unnecessary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write a script to stash things in a directory somewhere named for the branch, and have your checkout ritual check for a switch and swap contents as needed.

Comment: @jthill: that's a good idea.  I will try that next time i get a chance unless someone has another solution to offer.  thank you.